# Multisorting 2d array by first row alphabetically, then by second row's "j F Y" dates

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

I have everything in place with no errors and everything seems correct. I am trying to output the names and dates in ascending order while using print_r() to verify the order.

```
$win = array(
    'Name' => array(
        'Jane Doe ',
        'Nash Patel ',
        'Joe Public '
    ), 
    'Date' => array(
        '7 October 2015 ',
        '14 October 2014 ',
        '12 October 2016 '
    )
);

foreach($win as $element => $namedate) {
    echo '<strong>' . $element . '</strong><br>';
    foreach($namedate as $both) {
        echo $both . '<br/>';
    }
}

foreach ($win as $c => $key) {
    $sort_date[] = $key['Date'];
    $sort_name[] = $key['Name'];
}
array_multisort($sort_name, SORT_ASC, $sort_date, SORT_ASC, $win);
print_r($win);
```

OUTPUT\

```
Array (
    [Date] => Array (
        [0] => 7 October 2015 
        [1] => 14 October 2014 
        [2] => 12 October 2016 
    )
    [Name] => Array (
        [0] => Jane Doe 
        [1] => Nash Patel 
        [2] => Joe Public 
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't work as is? It seems to work for me?

Comment: @DrRoach When I output this code it shows exactly what i've entered however it doesn't output the dates in ascending order, i.e 2015 is outputted before 2014

Comment: Are the dates not sorted at all? Or are they sorted in the wrong direction?

Comment: @DrRoach I have added my output to the post so you can see for yourself. It isn't sorted at all by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the docs and it seems that

`array_multisort($sort_name, SORT_ASC, $sort_date, SORT_ASC, $win);`

means that $win will be sorted by name and date, but sorting by name has bigger priority over date.

Try adding more `Jane Doe` with different dates to see that they're sorted with date.

Comment: Would it be easier to sort the dates and names individually and then print them separately?

Comment: it depends what you are trying to accomplish, are the dates connected with the names (like date is a join date of person with the name) or just completely different data? If the data are not related and you need just sorted both sets then yes, just sort them separately.

Comment: they are meant to be joint but they can be sorted separately.

Comment: Well - then you answered your question. If you are sure you can sort them separately - sort them separately.

Comment: @meta agree, then there is no problem all of the sudden.

Comment: I just assumed there was a way to output both

Answer (score 0):

Because you say the arrays don't need to be sorted together here is how to split them and sort them separately.

```
$win = array('Name'=> 
                    array('Jane Doe ', 'Nash Patel ', 'Joe Public '), 
         'Date'=>
                    array('7 October 2015 ', '14 October 2014 ', '12 October 2016 '));


$dates = $win["Date"]; //split array
$names = $win["Name"]; //split array

usort($dates, "date_sort"); // custom sort on dates
asort($names); // sort names

var_dump($dates);
Var_dump($names);


function date_sort($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/kLjRh

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "14 October 2014 "
  [1]=>
  string(15) "7 October 2015 "
  [2]=>
  string(16) "12 October 2016 "
}

 array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Jane Doe "
  [2]=>
  string(11) "Joe Public "
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Nash Patel "
}
```

Comment: I edited the code removing the '1)' as these were only here for demo and I forgot to remove them on the post

Comment: Also the output for the names are wrong because "Nash Patel" is not in Ascending order. J comes before N.

Comment: @madoreo so it's not date order you want to sort on?

Comment: yes I want to sort ascending on date order and name order.

Comment: But you can't sort both. If you do, the relation between the keys will be wrong. One of them must be not in order of you wish to maintain some kind of trackability backwards.

Answer (score 0):

When using multisort, all array arguments MUST contain the same element count.  You do not need to append `$win` as the last argument to affect the previously declared elements.

When passing arguments to the function, any arrays which can be modified by reference will be mutated.  Any arguments which are derived directly from a function return, will not be affected (and couldn't be retrieved anyhow).

Because the date format is not "big endian", you need to transform it into a set of values which can be simply sorted. Calling `strtotime()` on each value will suitably produce unix timestamp integers.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rPZpH))

```
array_multisort(
    $win['Name'],
    array_map('strtotime', $win['Date']),
    $win['Date']
);
var_export($win);
```